# WAS not starting up

Tags: jvm, websphere, eclipse-mars

WAS is not starting up and is throwing error :

```
Exception in thread "(unnamed thread)" java/lang/IllegalAccessError
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library jclse7b_28(14): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

There is no log.If anybody has encountered such issue and have a solution,Please revert.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not saying much about which WAS version, so this may not be relevant, but have you seen this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/263168/websphere-liberty-profile-illegalcharsetnameexcept.html

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV25293 will help you

Comment: This usually happens when you set incorrect JVM arguments, e.g. heap size in incorrect format. Please check `native_stderr.log` and `native_stdout.log` for clues.